# Unable to install grails plugin mongodb

Tags: grails, plugins, installation

I am using grails-2.0.4 version with GGTS ide. When i tried to install mongodb some errors occuring. I have tried in two ways.

```
      **1)compile ":mongodb:1.0.0.GA"**
```

Then it is getting this error:

| Loading Grails 2.0.4
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://plugins.grails.org/grails-mongodb/tags/RELEASE_1_0_0_GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.pom

```
Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://plugins.grails.org/grails-mongodb/tags/RELEASE_1_0_0_GA/grails-mongodb-1.0.0.GA.jar

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins//mongodb/1.0.0.GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.pom

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins//mongodb/1.0.0.GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.jar

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/core//mongodb/1.0.0.GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.pom

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/core//mongodb/1.0.0.GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.jar

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-mongodb/tags/RELEASE_1_0_0_GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.pom

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-mongodb/tags/RELEASE_1_0_0_GA/grails-mongodb-1.0.0.GA.jar

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2//mongodb/1.0.0.GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.pom

Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2//mongodb/1.0.0.GA/mongodb-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- :mongodb:1.0.0.GA

  ```
      **2) grails install-plugin C:\Documents and Settings\marao18\Desktop\gorm-mongodb-0.5.4**
  ```

  Then it is getting this error: Please help me anyone.

  ```
    | Loading Grails 2.0.4
  ```

  | Configuring classpath.
  | Environment set to development.....
  | Resolving plugin C:\Documents. Please wait...
  :: problems summary ::
  :::: ERRORS
  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://plugins.grails.org/grails-%5CDocuments/tags/RELEASE_and/%5CDocuments-and.pom

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://plugins.grails.org/grails-%5CDocuments/tags/RELEASE_and/grails-%5CDocuments-and.zip

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/C/%5CDocuments/and/%5CDocuments-and.pom

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/C/%5CDocuments/and/%5CDocuments-and.zip

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/C/%5CDocuments/and/%5CDocuments-and.pom

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.grails.org/grails/core/C/%5CDocuments/and/%5CDocuments-and.zip

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-%5CDocuments/tags/RELEASE_and/%5CDocuments-and.pom

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://svn.codehaus.org/grails/trunk/grails-plugins/grails-%5CDocuments/tags/RELEASE_and/grails-%5CDocuments-and.zip

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/C/%5CDocuments/and/%5CDocuments-and.pom

  Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/C/%5CDocuments/and/%5CDocuments-and.zip

| Error resolving plugin [name:\Documents, group:C, version:and]. Plugin not found.
| Error Plugin not found for name [C:\Documents] and version [and]

Comment: Post your entire BuildConfig.groovy

Comment: I want help from anyone, it's urgent please.